# Any ideas how to fix this weird tableview separator line formatting issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm attaching an image because this is kinda hard to explain, I've also mocked up what I actually want it to look like. I'm going to try to explain it to so that others might find the question.

Maybe you've run up against this before and know a fix?

Here is the image of what I have alongside a mockup of what I want:
[image]

On the left, what I have, the items in the table are not separated by separator lines but the empty lines cells are separated. Ideally, the empty cells would not be shown and the table would just end letting the background show and the items in the table would have separators between their cells.

This is the corresponding code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        NSMutableArray *withoutThing = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.containerOfLists];
        [withoutThing removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.containerOfLists = withoutThing;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.containerOfLists forKey:@"list of lists"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.containerOfLists count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.containerOfLists[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: In your datasource method for your last footer view, do `return [[UIView alloc]init];`That's one step that could do the trick. We'll need also your code to help you for the reste.

Comment: @Larme thanks! ..I think we were both editing at the same time just a second ago.

Comment: @Larme Sorry, I'm not sure where/what my "last footer view" is. #lostinwoods

Comment: @Larme ...maybe it's in the storyboard?

Comment: One fix! I had the separator line set to "single line etched" instead of "default" I changed it back to default and now the separator lines are showing between items again. 1/2 way there.

Comment: @OlegSobolev and Larme -- Thanks!! I'm going to try these answers as soon as I can (in about 5 hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
In the `Storyboard`, select your `UITableView`, set the `Separator` to `Single Line`, or by code with:
`[yourTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];`

In your code, do somewhere:
`[yourTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];`
Or the gray color you want.

Add this to your datasources methods (as the same level as `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath`):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5; //return correct number
}
```

in `ViewDidLoad` method call:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

Init cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell)
{
    //init the cell!
}

    cell.textLabel.text = self.containerOfLists[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why return "5" instead of the list count?

Comment: Cuz i type my code before topicstarter post her code! @Larme